# UIWebView WebThread Crash Only on iPhone

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a simple `UIWebView` inside a `UIViewController` that loads a webpage.

The iPad view for this works fine and loads the page. The iPhone version crashes with a `WebThread (3)` breakpoint.

[image]

The tried changing the page loaded to google.com and it worked fine. So I'm guessing something about the site I'm loading is causing the issue but in that case I would expect it to also crash on iPad.